# How to configure Kafka Connect API for Dynamic Index Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Hello Everyone I have a case when I am using Kafka Connect API for sinking my data to an Elasticsearch. Right now I have a problem with this. My configuration file is very simple

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=5
topics=myTopicKafka
topic.index.map=myTopicKafka:myIndexES-1
schema.ignore=true
key.ignore=true
connection.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
type.name=kafka-connect
batch.size=200
#linger.ms=500
```

But in ES I am using Curator for roll over the index

```
actions:
  # 1:
  #   action: create_index
  #   description: 'Create mwe.resource.locate index'
  #   options:
  #     name: 'myIndexES-1-%Y-%m-%d-1'
  2:
    action: rollover
    description: >-
      Rollover the index associated with alias 'myIndexES', after exceeds 500MB memory or is a day old
    options:
      name: all_myIndexES
      conditions:
        max_age: 1d
        max_size: 500mb
```

This is creating a new Index every 500MB but with the Index name with myIndexES-00002, myIndexES-00003 and so on. So my question in here is how to support this with Kafka Connect API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [Rollover API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html), you're supposed to write to an alias pointing at a single index.

This means that in your elasticsearch-sink configuration, you should have this instead:

```
topic.index.map=myTopicKafka:myIndexES-write
```

And in your [Curator configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/rollover.html#_required_settings_10), you should have a name property with the name of your alias.

```
options:
  name: 'myIndexES-write'
```

Comment: Thanks, but now Kafka Connect API get a very but very bad performance of indexing after putting the index and working with that.